# Wordpress standalone comments page - with pagination

Tags: php, pagination, comments, wordpress

I want to build a page that would display *all comments*, regardless of which post they're attached to. I also want that page to be paginated, since it'll potentially have 10,000+ comments.

---

I'm not sure how to go about it, but here are some of the functions I've studied so far:

1. [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) - If no `post_id` is passed in, it'll return all comments. However, I don't see a way to paginate these (there are `offset` and `number` options to fiddle with, but that's *very* tedious to do manually).
2. [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) - The documentation on this is pretty bad, but [the source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1415) suggests that we can loop over all comments if used in conjunction with `get_comments`, by passing in the `get_comments` array as a second argument. This however would still use `get_comments` to actually... well, get the comments, and there seems to be no way to paginate that.
3. [`previous_comments_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_comments_link) & [`next_comments_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_comments_link) - These seem to only work in conjunction with `wp_list_comments` (with no second argument).
4. [`paginate_comments_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links) - Also looks like it only works with `wp_list_comments` (with no second argument).

---

## What I've tried:

1. Simply using the `number` argument in `get_comments`:

   ```
   $comments = get_comments(array(
       'status'    => 'approve',
       'number'    => '2'
   ));

   wp_list_comments(array(
       'callback' => 'my_rendering_function'
   ), $comments);

   paginate_comments_links();
   ```

   This does not display any pagination links.
2. The method suggested here: [**Display latest comments on page with pagination**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/display-latest-comments-on-page-with-pagination)

   ```
   $comments = get_comments(array(
       'status' => 'approve'
   ));

   wp_list_comments('per_page=2', $comments);

   paginate_comments_links();
   ```

   This doesn't either work (it shows the first 2 comments, but no pagination). Also, I cringe at `get_comments` loading *all* comments into memory.

---

## Question:

How can I paginate *all* comments?

---

**P.S.** I'm using WordPress 3.4.1 & PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: i don't see a direct way to do this and you in end need to make use of `offset` and `number` to get required comments to display.Have a look at the SEO pager plugin and you can get there pagination functionality else use Custom WordPress Loops to achieve your functionality.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi - Did you read [the linked-to post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/display-latest-comments-on-page-with-pagination)? It seems that there should be a way to do it. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your planning to build your own pagination, you will need to know the total number of comments your going to be using and thus your going to have to load all comments.

I've built below what i would use, let me know if it helps.

```
#Config here.
define('DEFAULT_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE',100);

$page = (int) (!isset($_REQUEST["page"]) ? 1 : $_REQUEST["page"]);
$limit = DEFAULT_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE;
$offset = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
$param = array(
    'status'=>'approve',
    'offset'=>$offset,
    'number'=>$limit,
);
$total_comments = get_comments(array('status'=>'approve'));
$pages = ceil(count($total_comments)/DEFAULT_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE);
$comments = get_comments($param);
foreach($comments as $comment) {
    // ECHO THE AUTHOR AND COMMENT
    echo("<strong>{$comment->comment_author}</strong> - {$comment->comment_content}");
}
$args = array(
'base'         => 'https://example.com/all-comments/%_%',
'format'       => '?page=%#%',
'total'        => $pages,
'current'      => $page,
'show_all'     => False,
'end_size'     => 1,
'mid_size'     => 2,
'prev_next'    => True,
'prev_text'    => __('&laquo; Previous'),
'next_text'    => __('Next &raquo;'),
'type'         => 'plain');
// ECHO THE PAGENATION 
echo paginate_links( $args );
```

Comment: Just to improve my previous answer, you don't need to physically fetch all the comments but you should at least know x in front of where you are. EG 25 a page you may want to show something like 1,2,3,4,... and so you would need to know if you have enough comments to fill those pages or if you must stop early. simply getting 4x25 would help you find out this information. If you want to know total pages you will still need to know the total number of comments.

Comment: This code works but in line 14 @PsyKzz probably intended: `$comments = get_comments($param);`

Comment: And in line 20 you may also want to fill in the base URL for the pagination function, e.g. `'base' => 'https://example.com/all-comments/%_%'`. See the [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for paginate_links() for more. The pagination wouldn't work for me unless I did this.

Answer (score 0):

We should worry about performance using get_comments() to get total comments. Must use the parameter offset as false, and count as true, like so:

```
$comments_per_page = 2;
$page = 2;

//MYSQL: LIMIT offset, number
$params = array(
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'offset' => (--$page) * $comments_per_page,
    'number' => $comments_per_page,
);

$comments = get_comments( $params );
$total_comments = get_comments(
    array_merge($params, 
            array(
                'count' => true,
                'offset' => 0,
                'number' => 0
            )
    )
);


$args = array(
    'total'     => ceil( $total_comments / $comments_per_page ),
    'current'   => max( 1, $page ),
);

$pagination = paginate_links( $args );
```

Add any parameter you need. You could use wp_list_comments() as weel, but if you want to customise the output HTML, use foreach for $comments:

```
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :

    echo $comment->comment_date;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $comment->comment_author;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $comment->comment_content;

endforeach;
```